# Navigate to new instance of page in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, navigateuri

I have an issue where I have a hyperlinkbutton (exists in the master page) that navigates to a "Project" page without any id, and therefore creates a new project as nothing exists. However, if I've done that, and clicks on the same button again, nothing happens. Is it possible to solve this somehow?

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 10 10 0" ToolTipService.Placement="Top" Style="{StaticResource NewProjectButtonStyle}" IsTabStop="False" NavigateUri="/Project/"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new parameter containing the time of the day in ticks, so all the urls are unique and it will reload. A bit of a hack, but works. If you have any other ideas for how to do this better, then let me know.